# Multiple conditions radio buttons

Tags: radio-button

I'm trying to create a questionaire that uses radio buttons and submit.  I have most of the work done (perhaps not pretty, but it works as intended) except that after I add up the radio button selections (every "Agree"=1 "Disagree"=0) I want to do another condition and return that.  Right now I just return the sum of the radio selections.  I want to be able to do something like:

```
if (z=0)
{
r="Black";
}
else if (z=1)
{
r="Blue";
}
else
{
r="Red";
}
```

And so on...

My current piece of code is as follows but where do I put the new piece to make it work?:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Form radio button checking</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
var r; 
function checkValue() // if you pass the form, checkValue(form)
{

     var form = document.getElementById('formType'); // if you passed the form, you wouldn't need this line.
     for(var i = 0; i < form.q1.length; i++)
     {
          if(form.q1[i].checked)
          {
          var selectedValue = form.q1[i].value;
          }

if(form.q2[i].checked)
          {
          var selectedValue2 = form.q2[i].value;
          }
if(form.q3[i].checked)
          {
          var selectedValue3 = form.q3[i].value;
          }
var z = Number(selectedValue) + Number(selectedValue2)+ Number(selectedValue3)



}


 document.getElementById("tot").innerHTML=z;
 return false;    

}




</script>


</head>

<body>

<form id="formType" method="post" action="#" onSubmit="return checkValue();" > <!-- you can pass the form here as well by doing: return checkValue(this);  -->
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>QUESTIONS</td>
<td>ANSWERS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Question 1</td>
<td><input type="radio" id="1"    name="q1" value=1> Agree<input type="radio" id="2"     name="q1" value=0> Disagree</td>    
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Question 2</td>
<td><input type="radio" id="3"    name="q2" value=1> Agree<input type="radio" id="4"     name="q2" value=0> Disagree</td>    
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Question 3</td>
<td><input type="radio" id="5"    name="q3" value=1> Agree<input type="radio" id="6"     name="q3" value=0> Disagree</td>    
</tr>

</table>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<p id="tot">Result will display here</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to do the calculation when you submit, so it should go in your OnSubmit function.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are asking for..

But if you are looking to assign a value to 'r' based on 'z' code should work.
Just add it anywhere under where you declare 'z'

```
if (z=0)
{
r="Black";
}
else if (z=1)
{
r="Blue";
}
else
{
r="Red";
}

alert(r);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use alert, I don't like popup boxes.  If you try the code I already have, the sum of the "Agree" selected appears on the page on submit.  I've tried to add the new code where I thought it would logically go and yet the entire thing fails to work.

Comment: In theory, I should be able to add my new code right before this line:
document.getElementById("tot").innerHTML=z; and then change that line to document.getElementById("tot").innerHTML=r;   instead of z

Comment: Aha, the new code should have been with == not single =

if (z==0)
{
r="Black";
}
else if (z==1)
{
r="Blue";
}
else
{
r="Red";
}

Comment: The ALERT was just to see the result. Not for production use